# Convert FLAC to MP3 with GStreamer + Python?

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer

Here's the command I'm trying to replicate:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=test.flac ! flacdec ! lame ! filesink location=test.mp3
```

When I run this command it works beautifully. I've tried to replicate this using the Pythong bindings with no luck at all. I don't get any errors with either of these scripts, but they don't work as expected:

When I run this script I just get an empty MP3 file:

```python
import gst
pipeline = gst.parse_launch('filesrc location="test.flac" ! flacdec ! lame ! filesink location="test.mp3"')
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
```

When I run this script I get a corrupt MP3 file:

```python
import gst

converter = gst.Pipeline('converter')

source = gst.element_factory_make('filesrc', 'file-source')
source.set_property('location', 'test.flac')

decoder = gst.element_factory_make('flacdec', 'decoder')

encoder = gst.element_factory_make('lame', 'encoder')

sink = gst.element_factory_make('filesink', 'sink')
sink.set_property('location', 'test.mp3')

converter.add(source, decoder, encoder, sink)

source.link(sink)

converter.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gstreamer uses GObject as a framework, so you need to run `gobject.MainLoop()` to start message flow in pipeline:

```
import gobject
import gst
pipeline = gst.parse_launch('filesrc location="test.flac" ! flacdec ! lame ! filesink location="test.mp3"')
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

gobject.threads_init()
gobject.MainLoop().run()
```

In the second example you also need to run MainLoop and link all the pipeline elements (e.g. with `element_link_many`).
You connected only source to sink, so your actual pipeline is just `filesrc ! filesink`.

Here is corrected code:

```
import gobject
import gst

converter = gst.Pipeline('converter')

source = gst.element_factory_make('filesrc', 'file-source')
source.set_property('location', 'test.flac')

decoder = gst.element_factory_make('flacdec', 'decoder')
encoder = gst.element_factory_make('lame', 'encoder')

sink = gst.element_factory_make('filesink', 'sink')
sink.set_property('location', 'test.mp3')

converter.add(source, decoder, encoder, sink)
gst.element_link_many(source, decoder, encoder, sink)

converter.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

gobject.threads_init()
gobject.MainLoop().run()
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! You have no idea how much time I wasted trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Some people end up at this answer looking for the command line / bash solution.  Here is a good conversion script.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Take a lossless flac audio track from and transcode it as a constant rate mp3 playable on some older audio equipment that can't play mp4s or variable bit rate mp3's.

if [ -z "$1" ];then
   echo usage: $0 [infile.flac]
   exit
fi

INFILE=$(basename $1)
WKDIR=$(dirname $1)
OUTFILE=$WKDIR/$( echo $INFILE | sed 's/\.flac//').mp3

#play ===================
#gst- launch filesrc location=1.flac \
#! flacdec \
#! autoaudiosink

#transcode ==============
gst-launch filesrc location=$INFILE \
! queue \
! flacdec \
! audioconvert \
! audioresample \
! lamemp3enc quality=2 target=bitrate bitrate=192 cbr=true \
! id3v2mux \
! filesink location=$OUTFILE
```